# Interchanging differentiation with sup (here: max)

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = \max_{a\in A} g(x,a)$, where $f:{\Bbb R}\rightarrow{\Bbb R}$ and $g:{\Bbb R}\times A\rightarrow{\Bbb R}$, where $A$ is discrete set (finite in applications). The function $g$ is assumed to be differentiable w.r.t. $x$.

Then $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\max_a g(x+h,a)-\max_a g(x,a)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\max_a [g(x+h,a)-g(x,a)]}{h} \stackrel{!}{=} \max_a \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+h,a)-g(x,a)}{h} = \max_a g_x(x,a).$$
Not sure about the penultimate step.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can't assume the $a$ which maximises $g(-,a)$ for $x$ and $x+h$ are the same, so
$$
\max_a g(x+h,a) - \max_a g(x,a) \neq \max_a [g(x+h,a)-g(x,a)]
$$
and you can't swap the order of $\max_a$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}$, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks. I‘ve overlooked this.